# reading values from XML Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, xslt

[image]

I have uploaded the XML screenshot. The structure of the xml is divided into levels, So based on a level I need only the levels which are below it.
For example level 1 can be identified by Name and Code tag so I want level 2 of a specific level 1 for which the code matches.

I have written the Javascript for parsing this XML but I am not get what I need

```
$('#permissionproperty_1').on("change",function () {
    var code = $(this).val().trim();
    var i;
    var xmlDoc;
    //var xml = "<rss version='2.0'>" + $('#hidXML').val() + "</rss>";
    var xml = "<xml version='1.0'>" + $('#hidXML').val() + "</xml>";
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
    var nodes = $(xmlDoc).find('Node')
    //alert(nodes.length);
    for (j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++) {
        var level = nodes[j].getAttribute('level');
        if (level == 1) {
            var name = nodes[j];
            var na = $(name).length;
            var child = $(name).find('Code').text().trim();
            if (child.indexOf(code) != -1) {
                for (i = 0; i < na; i++) {
                    var level1 = nodes[i].getAttribute('level');
                    if (level1 == 2) {
                        var name1 = $(node[i]).find('Node').find('Name').text().trim();
                        var code1 = $(node[i]).find('Node').find('Code').text().trim();
                        alert(name1 + " : Name   code :" + code1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```